# Authenticating a user using Forms Authentication in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, forms-authentication

I am using mvc and in my controller I have the following code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LoginViewModel model, string password)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (new BAUser().GetUserbyUsername(model.UserName) != null)
            {
                UserTable u = new UserTable();
                u = new BAUser().GetUserbyUsername(model.UserName);

                if (u.Password == model.Password)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(u.Username, u.Password);
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(u.Username, false);
                    Session["LoggedUser"] = u;
                    **if(Request.IsAuthenticated == true)
                    {
                        UserTable user = u;
                    }**
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");                    }

            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

The if statement with the ** was made just to test using breakpoints whether the request is being authenticated or not. However the authentication process does not seem to be working. Is there anything that I am doing wrong? I am using VS 2013

I found a workaround using sessions, however if anyone finds a solution to this please let me know.

Comment: What is the output of this like : FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(u.Username, u.Password);

Comment: That will just store the username and password in the authentication process, normally when I do if(request.Isauthenticated) it should see these values rather than null and return true not false. I switched over from vs 2010 to 2013 and this part is giving me problems.

Comment: No Authenticate method authenticates a user and return a boolean. You care getting null cause you are not being authenticated properly. Put a break point in FormAuthentication.Authenticate(u,p) and inspect the result and see what's returned.

Comment: For some reason it seems to work on VS 2010 though, it's on 2013 that is gives me problems